# MySql delete from other table

Tags: mysql, delete-row

i have two tables

table1:

```
pnr, dmax
01,  2017-02-02 11:10:00
02,  2017-05-02 10:10:10
```

and table2:

```
pnr, type, loc, dt
01,  c3,   l2,  2017-02-02 11:10:00
01,  c3,   l2,  2017-01-01 09:00:00
01,  c3,   l3,  2017-01-01 07:54:30
02,  c5,   l1,  2017-02-05 01:10:00
02,  c5,   l2,  2017-03-01 19:00:10
02,  c5,   l3,  2017-05-02 10:10:10
```

i like to delete all rows in Table2 which pair is NOT found in Table1 but i'm stuck with my limited mysql knowledge

something like ..... where pnr = pnr AND dmax != dt

please help

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE  table2
FROM    table2
        LEFT JOIN table1
            ON table1.pnr = table2.pnr AND table1.dmax = table2.dt
WHERE   table1.pnr IS NULL
```

The statement above uses a basic LEFT JOIN. This will return NULL in the right table where no records are found in the left and those are the records we want to delete so we add the IS NULL to the where clause

Comment: well spotted - now amended

Comment: OK, added a basic explanation

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick help. It is work as i expected

Answer (score 0):

You would need:
`DELETE FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.pnr, a.dmax FROM table1 a WHERE a.pnr = table2.pnr AND a.dmax = table2.dt)`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. After all, to be sure, i wrote a PHP program to achieve needed logic (PHP is anyway part of main program) but i wanted to skip writing PHP. Your query delete far more rows than i expected. 
Answer below by @SEarle1986 working exactly with same result as PHP. Anyway, thank you for your help again